# how to give sudo permission to logging file?

Tags: python, logging

I setup logging as below but the logging fails because the location `/gerrit_v2/hooks/changemergedlogs` needs sudo permissions ,how do I give sudo permissions through the script?

CODE:-

```
import os,time,logging

# setup logging
changemergedhooklog = 'change_merged_hook_log_' + time.strftime("%m%d%Y") + '_' + time.strftime("%H%M%S") + '.txt'
#log = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),changemergedhooklog)
log = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),'changemergedlogs',changemergedhooklog)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
#logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.setLevel(10)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
#ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setLevel(10)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(filename)-15s %(funcName)-20s %(lineno)-5s  %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s', datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

fh = logging.FileHandler(log, 'w')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

ERROR:-

```
  File "copytest.py", line 17, in <module>
    fh = logging.FileHandler(log, 'w')
  File "/Network/Servers/nwna40a.apple.com/vol/homedir4/wgerrit/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 903, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/Network/Servers/nwna40a.apple.com/vol/homedir4/wgerrit/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 926, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/gerrit_v2/hooks/changemergedlogs/change_merged_hook_log_03272019_142144.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your script as root or with sudo.

If this is not an option you can detect when you're not running with sudo calling `os.geteuid()`. If `os.geteuid() != 0` you're not running with sudo. If this is the case you can call yourself again but this time with sudo, something like `subprocess.call(['sudo', 'python3', *sys.argv])`.

Comment: I dont have an option to call the script as its a gerrit hook triggered by gerrit,so looking for other options